# How to find reputed conference and journal?

Tags: publications, research-process

How to find the upcoming call for papers in scopus journal and top rated conference? And how to ensure that conference proceedings will be listed in scopus?
Most of the conference doesn't endorse anything about their indexing. How to confirm about the indexing details?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Academia SE.  Unfortunately, it's unclear what you're asking here - can you revise your question to be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

Any reputable journal or conference will have **an associated website** on which you can find a call for papers. Searching google for the name and year of the conference will typically reveal the website in the first few hits.

On a **conference website**, you typically find the call under a heading similar to one of the following:

- *Call for papers*
- *Call for contributions*
- *Contributors*
- *Submission Guidelines*
- *Research*

On a **journal website for IEEE**, there is usually a *Submit a Manuscript* link on the left-hand panel of the page. Any calls for special issues will probably be announced directly on the main page.

Similarly, on a **journal website for Elsevier**, there is usually a *Submit a paper* link on the left-hand panel, and **for Springer**, there is usually an *Instructions for authors* link on the right-hand panel (but ensure that you are on the journal page at `springer.com`, not at `SpringerLink`). Other publishers usually have similar webpage designs, because they want authors to easily find their calls.

The Scopus blog [describes how to check if a paper is indexed](http://blog.scopus.com/posts/titles-indexed-in-scopus-check-before-you-publish): the easiest option they suggest is to search by title in their database.

Comment: @ schester thanks for your info. Is there any forum or discussion group to know about the upcoming conference details (i.e. Deadlines and area)?

Comment: @Jayanth There are often are, yes, but I think each is typically quite specific to one research area. It would be worth asking somebody in your field where announcements of upcoming deadlines/job postings/calls are made. But it is also worth getting to know the top-ranked conferences/journals in your field, and then investigating them directly, since the annual deadlines (for conferences, anyway) typically do not vary much from year to year.