# Conference and Journal Ranking Websites

Tags: publications, journals, conference, ranking

I had a hard time deciphering conference and journal rankings in order to find good places to publish. [Disclaimer - I am a computing PhD and this post is intended to have a strong focus in CS]

I think it would be beneficial to have a list of websites which rank conferences and journals (deffo. for my self and maybe others too). My question is, could you all help me build this list?

Conferences:

- [Conference Ranks](http://www.conferenceranks.com/)
- [Core Conference Portal](http://portal.core.edu.au/conf-ranks/)
- [Computer Science Conference Rankings](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~zaiane/htmldocs/ConfRanking.html)

Journals:

- [Scimago](http://www.scimagojr.com/)
- [Core Journal Portal](http://portal.core.edu.au/jnl-ranks/)

Other posts readers might be interested in:

- [How to find reputed conference and journal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/59613/how-to-find-reputed-conference-and-journal)
- [Impact factor vs journal ranking](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/31044/what-is-the-relationship-between-impact-factor-and-journal-ranking)
- [Rankings of Computer Science conferences and journals](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26807/rankings-of-computer-science-conferences-and-journals)
- [Difference between conference paper and journal paper](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18349/difference-between-conference-paper-and-journal-paper)

Comment: Someone also mention "Webascience" but I haven't been able to find this ranking service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other conference ranking include:

[CORE Conference Portal](http://portal.core.edu.au/conf-ranks/)

Also useful reading [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_any_official_and_credible_conference_ranking_or_impact_factor_list), a Research Gate post

Answer (score 0):

Find the journal with the highest impact factor; that's the 'best'. I recall reading that in CS, conference presentations take the place of papers (as the field moves so fast). There is likely an informal 'ranking' of best conferences. It is almost certainly implicit knowledge; the only way to obtain it is to ask someone in the know. That will require asking a senior professor, or an emeritus professor, and/or one of their grad students.

Comment: I've been told there are websites (and I have included some) that will rank journals by impact factor. The point of this post is to find such websites and state them for others to use.

Comment: I feel like this is a "Let me Google that for you" sort of thing? There really isn't a strong 'question' to this question, and that sort of violates the ethos of StackExchange.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot this is a competition and shared knowledge is frowned upon. I for one think something which helps people is a good thing.

Comment: @abdnChap A big issue is that SE is not oriented toward being constantly updated, so in general a list like you're looking for would work better on Wikipedia or maintained by a grad student association for a given field. My sense is that the Academia StackExchange only sets up community wikis to address issues that constantly recur in slightly different forms that span academia, but in general do not want to create lists. I hope that you do come back with other questions, though.